# Student deport from UK want to move USA for study

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, bangladeshi-citizens, refusal

I am from Bangladesh. I have received an undergraduate degree from UK. When I applied after that for a postgraduate program, I was refused as I took a TOEIC exam and they said I committed fraud.

I would like to state that I renewed my visa twice before I was refused with the same TOEIC test reason. I was in detention for a while and I have got the appeal rights from my back home.

Now I would like to apply for a US F1 visa. Is my UK visa refusal and detention going to affect my visa application? My passport doesn't have any sign of refusal. Please suggest to me what should I do. I have done my IELTS now and I made a score 6.

Comment: Are you in Bangladesh right now?

Answer (score 1):

The visa officials will judge everything on the balance of the evidence you present. One of the questions you will be asked is if you have ever been refused a visa? You may be asked to sign a waiver allowing them to get a copy of your immigration history from the UK. It would be naive to assume that this won't be considered. But it won't be the only thing considered. They will look at finances, in particular financial history, school performance, school quality and accreditation, overall character, work history, etc....

I think the biggest thing that would concern me if I was the case worker would be the overstay-until-deportation proceedings. No matter what went on beforehand, the United States is going to want to be sure that you will abide by the restrictions placed on your stay, even it is the result of unfair or unlucky visa refusal.